# Nginx upgrade from 1.16 to 1.18 failed due to module discrepancy on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, apt

I installed Nginx 1.18.0 using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147144/how-to-upgrade-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04/1148829#1148829) guide, however, the install failed with the following error:

`nginx: [emerg] module "/etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_dav_ext_module.so" version 1016001 instead of 1018000 in /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-dav-ext.conf:1 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

I tried to install with
`apt install libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext`, but received the following:

`libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext is already the newest version (1.16.1-0+xenial1).`

I currently have the line `include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` commented out, but this cannot stay, since it is a production server. Why is the error showing `1.16.1-0+xenial1` when I installed `1.18.0`?

Comment: You're mixing packages from different repositories. Your `nginx` is from official repo, while  `libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext` is from Ubuntu repo. Either remove Ubuntu NGINX packages, e.g. `libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext` or remove NGINX from the official repo and use Ubuntu packages only.

Comment: If I use Ubuntu version, the Nginx version is not high enough for compliance. I have to be using > 1.16.

Comment: Then remove all “libnginx*” packages. They link against old

Comment: Thanks. Then how would I install them correctly after that? Would I need to recompile Nginx with the needed modules?